# C# Excel Missing First and Last Cell Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a project where I am getting data from an excel spreadsheet (xls). Now its working perfectly on most spreadsheets but sometimes it is missing the first cell and the last cell's data.

Here's my code..

```
        //Get the range data
        //
        var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            sheet + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
        con.Open();

        //Create Dataset and fill with imformation from the Excel Spreadsheet for easier refrence
        var myDataSet = new DataSet();

        var myCommandCol = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM [Tubing$A15:F28]", con);
        myCommandCol.Fill(myDataSet);

        if (myDataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var report = new report
                {                       
                    item1 = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    item2 = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    item3 = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString()
                };
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```

So it is getting all the data between H15 and F28, but not those cells.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: query quate mismatch : change  "SELECT * FROM [Tubing$A15:F28"]" to  "SELECT * FROM [Tubing$A15:F28]"

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: check that cells not merged or other opposite properties